# Removing mould from a painted skirting board - won't wipe off?

Tags: mold, skirting

I have some green patches of mould appearing on a painted skirting board at a corner and along an external wall.

I have used White Wine vinegar spray and wiped away but the mould mostly remains.

However, the mould comes away if I pick at it with a fingernail. I suspect that if I used something slightly more abrasive than a cloth I could get this mould off.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try a toothbrush

***Warning: my skirting boards have mould *under* the paint because they were painted white over the top of existing cream-coloured thick gloss! And the room has serious intrinsic damp issues!***

This is how I resolved my own problem **(a little paint did come away but the mould came out at last)**:

1. Spray white vinegar solution on the affected area to kill mould and dampen it to reduce release of mould spores
2. Leave to work for 10 minutes
3. Spray white vinegar solution on an old toothbrush
4. Use the toothbrush with a scrubbing action to gently disturb the mould lodged in the paint
5. Air out room to address white vinegar smell and any mould spores

### What I should have done - in a perfect world

1. Persuaded landlord to address inherent damp issues with this room
2. Sanded down the skirting boards, removing mould and previous paint
3. Paint with an anti-mould paint

Answer (score 2):

Here in Florida green mold is common with the humidity. We clean it off with a 50/50 solution of water and outdoor bleach. ( bleach that is not harmful to plants).
Spray or brush the solution on. Give it 5 to 10 minutes to work. ( longer times for worse cases). Brush with a medium to soft bristle brush, then rinse with fresh water.
Wear protection for your eyes and skin as the solution is caustic.
It may be a good idea to examine what is causing the mold and correcting that if possible.